# Cannot insert white spaces in string in the examples table

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

```
Feature:player
@all

  Scenario Outline:Where is the player

    Given I navigate to Google
    When I enter < player> in the search field
    Then the text < keyword1> should be present

    @current @football
    Examples:
      | player  | keyword1   |
      | Rooney  | Manchester |
      | Gerrard | Liverpool  |
      | Terry   | Chelsea    |
    @old @football
    Examples:
      | player          | keyword1   |
      | Eric Cantona    | Manchester |
```

If I write Cantona instead of Eric Cantona then it is working, but as soon as you run the program with white space inserted in a string it gives an error.

Comment: Can you show your `step_definition` line?

Comment: Can you also give us the error it is returning? Just FYI, I already used spaces in examples and they worked.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivdh1bycy8udtk5/step_project.rb

Comment: here's the link to my step_definition file

Comment: !!!!!!This is the error message !!!!!!You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
When (/^I enter Eric Cantona in the search field$/) do
   pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Answer (score 3):

Try putting quotes around the Scenario Outline placeholders (and removing the leading space from the placeholder).  For example:

```
Scenario Outline: Where is the player

  Given I navigate to Google
  When I enter "<player>" in the search field
  Then the text "<keyword1>" should be present
```

Comment: Both the answers are saying the same thing, but adding quotes around example variable used in gherkin is always the best practice.. and that should be the direction followed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your step definition is only looking for a single word:

```
When /^I enter (\w+) in the search field$/ do | player |
```

Cucumber uses regular expressions to match steps to their definitions, and to capture the variables. Your step definition is looking for `"I enter "`, followed by a single word, followed by `" in the search field"`.

You could change the "player" regex from `(\w+)` to something like `([\w\s]+)`. That would match words and white space and should match the multi word example.

```
When /^I enter ([\w\s]+) in the search field$/ do | player |
```

Alternatively if you surround your variables with quotes (as suggested by orde) then Cucumber should generate step definitions which match anything inside the quotes using a (.*) group.

Comment: Thank you, you saved heck of a time.